# MySql - best approach

Tags: mysql

I have about 500 rows in a table to update daily based on a JavaScript object. Most will already exist in the table and have the same values as the new data. Some may be new in the javascript object. Some may be in the table, but not in the object. 
As well as the key, and several other fields, there are two date fields, 'dateCreated' and 'lastUpdated'

If the key (eg 4567654) does not exist, I want to insert the row, and set 'dateCreated' to today.

If the key exists, and values are the same, I want to set the 'lastUpdated' field to today.

If it does exist, with changed values, I want to insert the new row, but retain the old values. I'm thinking of either amending the existing key by adding a suffix (4567654_1) or moving the old row to an archive table.

What's my best approach?

Comment: 'If the key exists, and values are the same, I want to set the 'lastUpdated' field to today'. is counter intuitive since nothing has changed. I would not mess around with a key field by adding a suffix or version surely a combination of key, creation date would be sufficient to get the most recent version.

Comment: The answer to this kind of question is generally _it depends_.

Comment: There's simply no way to determine the best design when you don't know what the data means or represents. You also seem to be suggesting a 500 row table as example of a huge dataset that needs careful optimisations—if you have performance issues so far, you've possibly got some basic stuff wrong (lack of indexes, redundant looped queries...).

Comment: @P.Salmon It's probably the field name that is wrong, and maybe 'lastSeen' would be better. Items can drop out of the daily feed, and then it would be good to know when they last appeared.

Comment: INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: you seem to have introduced a fourth scenario -  'Items can drop out of the daily feed'

Comment: The trigger is working well when there is a change in the data. It writes off the previous value to an archive table. I can also move the 'lastseen' field to a separate table, so that doesn't cause un-necessary updates. So it is slightly simplified scenario. The daily feed is either presenting new data , same data or changed data.  The likely proportions are 2% new, 96% same, 2% changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An insert on duplicate key will fire update triggers so perhaps you are looking for something like this

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t(id int primary key, val int, created_date datetime, lastLoaded datetime);
create table t1(archiveid  int auto_increment primary key,id int, val int, created_date datetime, lastLoaded datetime);
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t before insert on t
for each row
begin
        if not exists(select 1 from t where id = new.id) then
            set new.created_date = '2019-01-01 01:00:00';
            set new.lastloaded = '2019-01-01 01:00:00';
            insert into debug_table(msg1) values (concat(new.id,': notfound:',new.lastloaded));
        end if;

end $$

drop trigger if exists t2;
delimiter $$
create trigger t2 before update on t
for each row
begin
        set new.lastloaded = '2019-01-01 08:00:00';
        insert into debug_table(msg1) values (concat(new.id,': before update:',new.lastloaded));
        if new.val  <> old.val then
            insert into t1(id,val,created_date,lastloaded) values (old.id,old.val,old.created_date,old.lastloaded);
        end if;
end $$
delimiter ;

truncate table debug_table;
insert into t(id,val) values
(1,10),(2,20),(3,30)
on duplicate key
update val = values(val);
commit;

select * from t;

insert into t(id,val) values
(1,10),(2,20),(3,35)
on duplicate key
update val = values(val);

select * from t;
+----+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | val  | created_date        | lastLoaded          |
+----+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |   10 | 2019-01-01 01:00:00 | 2019-01-01 08:00:00 |
|  2 |   20 | 2019-01-01 01:00:00 | 2019-01-01 08:00:00 |
|  3 |   35 | 2019-01-01 01:00:00 | 2019-01-01 08:00:00 |
+----+------+---------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
select * from t1;
+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| archiveid | id   | val  | created_date        | lastLoaded          |
+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|         1 |    3 |   30 | 2019-01-01 01:00:00 | 2019-01-01 01:00:00 |
+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
select * from debug_table;
+----+--------------------------------------+
| id | msg1                                 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1: notfound:2019-01-01 01:00:00      |
|  2 | 2: notfound:2019-01-01 01:00:00      |
|  3 | 3: notfound:2019-01-01 01:00:00      |
|  4 | 1: before update:2019-01-01 08:00:00 |
|  5 | 2: before update:2019-01-01 08:00:00 |
|  6 | 3: before update:2019-01-01 08:00:00 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You don't need the debug_table it's only there to err... debug.